# ASP.Net timeout processing file after upload

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We have an ASP.Net web application on IIS7 that is used to upload Excel files and then load them into a SQL database by running jobs on the SQL server. The app will wait until the job completes then show the user a message. Due to some larger files being used the app is throwing the error below.

> Network Error (tcp_error)
>
> A communication error occurred: ""  The Web Server may be down, too
>   busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to
>   requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.  For assistance,
>   contact your network support team.

The app uses an asp:View to progress from various steps. I have tried to bump the session timeout and httpRuntime executionTimeout values to account for how long the job takes to run but it does not appear to have any effect. I know the job completes but the app isn't showing that feedback to the user. I think the error is thrown as the app hits the logic to display the user the view showing all the final messages.

I can only guess that a) there is another setting I'm not aware of for timeout, b) another config file setting is overruling my web config setting for the app, or c) the asp:View is counting all the various steps as one long process and not reseting the "clock" as each step is completed.

As I said, the file upload fine, and the job completes fine, the app just can't advance to that last step where it shows the user the view upon the end. Any ideas on what I can look for to fix this issue? My only other option would be to rewrite the app to not wait for the job to finish and handle notifying the user some other way.

**Update 1**
After further testing it appears the error is from the ASP.Net custom code we created that does a SQL bulk copy and not the running of the SQL job. The current test runs around 220 seconds testing locally but causes a timeout on a test server.

**Update 2**
After more research I'm inclinded to think user pevgeniev is correct and this is just a limiting factor of the browser. The only thing that prevents me from marking this as answered is I don't know why file uploads don't appear to have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error in the browser, than the timeout is on the client side, and there isn't much you could do server side. As you've suggested, you could rewrite the app, so that it polls for the result from the client, rather than expecting to finish the task in a single request.

Comment: Really? I assumed it was more server side configuration since the links I read at first all detailed examples of people trying to use the ASP upload control on large (500mb+) files. In those posts responders typically cited apps that could handle large files without timeout. Assuming the issues were related I had hoped it was just another config setting app or server side. Given that the step which causes the timeout is our SQL bulk copy ASP.Net code, it sounds like I'm stuck if it's a client/browser issue.

Comment: I think you are correct but I can't find anything to explain why the same problem doesn't happen with file uploads. Unless it's because the client is still active during a file upload so technically it isn't a timeout.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure for the file upload difference, but I also think it's because there is still active connection between browser and server, so technically the "request" is still not completed.